# Finding whather an array of custom model is a subset of another two dimensional array of same model in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, multidimensional-array, set

Hi i am new to stack overflow, I need some help with a problem that I have been dealing with for the past two days. so below is my json data that I am getting from an API

```
let json = """
{
    "exclusions": [
  [
    {
      "facility_id": "1",
      "options_id": "4"
    },
    {
      "facility_id": "2",
      "options_id": "6"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "facility_id": "1",
      "options_id": "3"
    },
    {
      "facility_id": "3",
      "options_id": "12"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "facility_id": "2",
      "options_id": "7"
    },
    {
      "facility_id": "3",
      "options_id": "12"
    }
  ]
]
}
"""
```

And I am parsing the json with decodable like below

```
required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws//Unwanted Parsing code is removed.
 {
let exclusions = try container.decode([[Exclusion]].self, forKey: .exclusions)
self.exclusions.append(exclusions)
}
```

Since I am using Relam for the persistence my Model class Looks like below

```
class Data: Object {
    dynamic var exclusions: List<DoubleExclusions> = List()
}

class DoubleExclusions: Object {
    dynamic var exclusionSet = List<Exclusion>()
    convenience init(_ exc: List<Exclusion>)
    {
    self.init()
    self.exclusionSet = exc
    }
}

class Exclusion: Object {
  dynamic var fId: String? = ""
  dynamic var oId: String? = ""
   convenience init(_ fid: String, _ oid: String) {
    self.init()
    self.fId = fid
    self.oId = oid
    }
    //parsingCodeRemoved
}
```

Once the data is fetched It will be saved in the DB.

I am making the custom "Exclusion" array from my tableview input to compare and check that data with the existing database exclusions list. for example:

I am getting [Exclusion(0,1), Exclusion(2,1), Exclusion(1,2)]
I want to check above arrays elements if they are present in a single "DoubleExclusions" objects list of exclusions where "DoubleExclusions" is also saved as a List in my "Data" class.

simply check [Exclusion(0,1), Exclusion(2,1), Exclusion(1,2)] is in [[Exclusion(0,1), Exclusion(2,1)],[Exclusion(3,4), Exclusion(4,2)],[Exclusion(0,1), Exclusion(3,2)]]

ex1:

input:[Exclusion(0,1), Exclusion(2,1), Exclusion(1,2)]
output: [[Exclusion(0,1), Exclusion(2,1)]]

ex2:
input:[Exclusion(0,1), Exclusion(2,1), Exclusion(3,2)]
output: [[Exclusion(0,1), Exclusion(2,1)], [Exclusion(0,1), Exclusion(3,2)]]

I have tried implementing the models with equatable, hashable and used "Set" operations but no luck so far.
please help me with how to go about it, scalable approach would be much better. Thanks

Comment: Not related to your question but you should name your class something else `Data` it is already a native swift type.

Comment: Why isn't (3,2) part of the output in your second example, it exists in the double list together with (0,1)?

Comment: It seems you're asking about an algorithm, but all your code is related to decoding or defining classes. Do you have any code related to the algorithm? If you post that, then maybe someone can see where you're getting off track.

Comment: @LeoDabus I have edited that here, it is named otherwise in the project

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it should be but  1 set of exclusions are enough for the app to show the restriction, even  if it returns a 2d array I would use the first index component, that's all needed now.

Comment: That did not make it any clearer for me.

Comment: @user695022 I have not implemented any algorithm for this, all I have tried are some filtering of arrays and intersection, subset  of Sets along with some messy iterations, if else cases which are not scalable at all.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson consider the output  let result = [[Exclusion(0,1), Exclusion(2,1)], [Exclusion(0,1), Exclusion(3,2)]]
 I would still use " result[0]", anyway I have edited the question.